# asterisk call blocking dial plan?

Tags: asterisk

I wrote simple dial plan in asterisk. This dial-plan target is to check caller-id of incoming call and hangup for specific numbers

but this dial-plan hangup all incoming call with diffrent caller-id.
So what do i do? ;(

```
   [general]  
    static=yes  
    writeprotect=yes  
    autofallthrough=yes  
    clearglobalvars=no  
    priorityjumping=yes  
    include "exten_gvars.inc"  
    
    [macro-queue]
    exten => s, 1, Queue(${ARG1})
    
    [default]  
    exten => s, 1, Answer  
    exten => s/9999, 2 ,Hangup  
    exten => s, 2, BackGround(welcome)  
    exten => s, 3, Macro(queue,operator)
```

Edit

i change my dial plan to this but it not working, incoming call hangup after two beep(i know it occur cuz a mistake in my dial plan)!

```
    [general]
static=yes
writeprotect=yes
autofallthrough=yes
clearglobalvars=no
priorityjumping=yes
#include "exten_gvars.inc"

[macro-monitor]
exten => s, 1, MixMonitor(${UNIQUEID}.wav)
exten => s, 2, SetCIDName(${UNIQUEID}#${CALLERIDNAME},a)

[macro-defaultLine]
exten => s, 1, Macro(monitor)
exten => s, 2, Dial(SIP/${ARG1},60,T)

[macro-queue]
exten => s, 1, Macro(monitor)
exten => s, 2, Queue(${ARG1})

[inbound]
exten => _XX, 1, Macro(defaultLine,${EXTEN})

[default]
exten => 123,1,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num)} = XX]?reject:allow)
exten => 123,n(allow),Answer
exten => 123,n,BackGround(welcome)
exten => 123,n,Macro(queue,operator)
exten => 123,n(reject),BackGround(WTF)
exten => 123,n,Hangup()
include => inbound
```

Comment: so let me make this question harder !!!!
 I Want if 9999 call, first hear a sound file and then hangup.

Comment: Please phrase your question as something better than "So what do i do?" If this isn't a programming question, perhaps http://superuser.com is a better venue.

Answer (score 13):

Here is your dialplan, assuming xxxxx is your target number

```
exten => 123,1,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num)} = xxxxx]?reject:allow)
exten => 123,n(allow),Dial(Zap/4)
exten => 123,n,Hangup()
exten => 123,n(reject),Playback(abandon-all-hope)
exten => 123,n,Hangup()
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: How this answer got so many upvotes is beyond me. I see this kind of dialplan all the time. Guys,what happens when you have 2 ex-girlfriends? or 50 ? How many times did you need to screen for 1 single number. Most often it is a list of numbers and list of prefixes. The GotoIf will not work. Use the dialplan as it was intended, or move to an AGI script if you feel like programming.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a step 2 for other callerids and autofalltrhough is enabled, which means (in 1.6) that the call will be dropped after step 1.

```
[default]
exten => s, 1, Answer
exten => s/9999, 2 ,Hangup
exten => s, 2, NoOp  
exten => s, 3, BackGround(welcome)
exten => s, 4, Macro(queue,operator)
```

**Edit:**
Are you sure the callerID is EXACTELLY 9999? 
Try replacing that line with

```
exten => s, 2, NoOp((${CALLERID(all)})
```

then look in the console and see what the callerID is.

use:

```
 asterisk -r
```

then enter:

```
 core set verbose 5
```

also, enter:

```
show dialplan
```

and see if the dialplan is correctly loaded into asterisk

Comment: I change my dial plan as like you said. but now for 9999 number call didn't hangup and all call same as as 9999 number, go to background step.

Comment: thanks but is there any solution for see caller id for incoming call or online calls. i check my voip gateway and see number, and input that number in my dial plan. thanks for your attention

Comment: The NoOp(${CallerID(all)}) will display the caller id on the asterisk console when that step is executed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would appear that you don't really understand how the Asterisk dialplan works. The code block you put up there is just plain wrong, Asterisk won't complain - as dialplan isn't supposed to do so.

Let's examine one by one:

```
[macro-queue]
exten => s, 1, Queue(${ARG1})

[default]  
exten => s, 1, Answer  
exten => s/9999, 2 ,Hangup  
exten => s, 2, BackGround(welcome)  
exten => s, 3, Macro(queue,operator)
```

The reason the above is wrong is due to the fact that you can't put a CALLERID matching on a single line of the extension - it's should be all the way. So technically, you would need:

```
[macro-queue]
exten => s, 1, Queue(${ARG1})

[default]  
exten => s/9999, 1, Answer  
exten => s/9999, 2 ,Hangup  
exten => s/9999, 2, BackGround(welcome)  
exten => s/9999, 3, Hangup 

exten => s, 1, Answer  
exten => s, 2 ,Hangup  
exten => s, 2, BackGround(welcome)  
exten => s, 3, Macro(queue,operator)
```

Now, that isn't a proper way of doing this - simply because you'll be replicating lines over and over again. The right way of doing it is very much similar to the previous answer, however, this is what I would do:

```
exten => s, 1, Answer
exten => s, n, Gotoif($["${CALLERID(num)}" = "9999"]?reject:continue)
exten => s, n(continue), Background(Welcome)
exten => s, n, Macro(queue, operator)
exten => s, n(reject), Hangup()
```

Now, you can extend the various CALLERID numbers you want to block. Again, assuming this is the result you were looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
[default]  
    exten => s/9999,1,Hangup  

    exten => s,1,Answer  
    exten => s,2,BackGround(welcome)  
    exten => s,3,Macro(queue,operator)
```